# Convert an image to base64 and vice versa

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I want to convert an image to base64 and back to image again.
Here is the code which i tried so far and the error also. Any suggestions please?

```
public void Base64ToImage(string coded)
{
    System.Drawing.Image finalImage;
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(coded);
    ms.Read(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    finalImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
    
    Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=LeftCorner.jpg");
    finalImage.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

The error is :

> Parameter is not valid.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.
>
> Source Error:

```
Line 34:             ms.Read(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
Line 35:             ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
Line 36:             finalImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
Line 37:         
Line 38:         Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
```

> Source File: e:\Practice Projects\FaceDetection\Default.aspx.cs    Line: 36

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are *reading* from an empty stream, rather than loading the existing data (`imageBytes`) *into* the stream. Try:

```
byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(coded);
using(var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes)) {
    finalImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
}
```

Also, you should endeavour to ensure that `finalImage` is disposed; I would propose:

```
System.Drawing.Image finalImage = null;
try {
    // the existing code that may (or may not) successfully create an image
    // and assign to finalImage
} finally {
    if(finalImage != null) finalImage.Dispose();
}
```

And finally, note that System.Drawing [***is not supported***](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx) on ASP.NET; YMMV.

> **Caution**
>
> Classes within the System.Drawing namespace are not supported for use within a Windows or ASP.NET service. Attempting to use these classes from within one of these application types may produce unexpected problems, such as diminished service performance and run-time exceptions. For a supported alternative, see Windows Imaging Components.

Comment: Still getting the same error in the line finalImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);

Answer (score 2):

The [MemoryStream.Read Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.read.aspx) reads bytes from the [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a84386f.aspx) into the specified byte array.

If you want to write the byte array to the [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a84386f.aspx), use the [MemoryStream.Write Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.write.aspx):

```
ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

Alternatively, you can simply wrap the byte array in a [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e55f3s5k.aspx):

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but didn't work! Can you please suggest any alternatives?