# Convert image file to base64 with rendering in a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image

I have image captcha and in all browsers except chrome, captcha always reloading the same picture.How can i pix that.Mb i need to convert my image to base64string, i tried set nocache attribute to my controller/actions but it doesn't work.

```
public ActionResult CaptchaImageComm(string prefix, bool noisy = false)
    {
        var rand = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
        //generate new question
        int a = rand.Next(10, 99);
        int b = rand.Next(0, 9);
        var captcha = string.Format("{0} + {1} = ?", a, b);

        //store answer
        Session["Captcha5"] = a + b;

        //image stream
        FileContentResult img = null;
        string result = null;
        using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
        using (var bmp = new Bitmap(130, 30))
        using (var gfx = Graphics.FromImage((System.Drawing.Image)bmp))
        {
            gfx.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;
            gfx.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            gfx.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));

            //add noise
            if (noisy)
            {
                int i, r, x, y;
                var pen = new Pen(Color.Yellow);
                for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    pen.Color = Color.FromArgb(
                    (rand.Next(0, 255)),
                    (rand.Next(0, 255)),
                    (rand.Next(0, 255)));

                    r = rand.Next(0, (130 / 3));
                    x = rand.Next(0, 130);
                    y = rand.Next(0, 30);

                    gfx.DrawEllipse(pen, x - r, y - r, r, r);
                }
            }

            //add question
            gfx.DrawString(captcha, new Font("Tahoma", 15), Brushes.Gray, 2, 3);

            //render as Jpeg
            bmp.Save(mem, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

            img = this.File(mem.GetBuffer(), "image/Jpeg");

        }
        return img;
    }
```

and my action :

```
<img alt="Captcha" src="@Url.Action("CaptchaImageComm", "DataCaptcha")" style="" />
```

I set the cache settings as follows:

```
filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1))‌​;
filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.A‌​llCaches);
filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCach‌​e);
filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

Comment: You need to set caching headers.

Comment: i set something like this

filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));


                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

but it not help

Comment: What do you see in Firebug's Network tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps another aproach could be to include a timestamp parameter with the current datetime to avoid caching. This technique is used sometimes to prevent caching webpages in browser, and perhaps can be used here. Just an idea.

Comment: i think i need convert img to base64string,but don't know exact how

Comment: I use the following link to convert images to base64 strings to attach them to emails: http://webcodertools.com/imagetobase64converter  If you want to convert it from code you can see for example this other StackOverflow post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7240216/convert-an-image-to-base64-and-vice-versa